# Custom Crawled and Managed Property not being returned in Graph API search

Tags: search, sharepoint, properties, microsoft-graph-api, managed

Custom site column and managed property is not returned in seach/query Graph API. Anything wrong with my mapping method?

Hi,

I'm a sharepoint site owner in my company and I created a site column called "SupplierName" and added it in one of my Lists.

[image: List photo]

A crawled property has been automatically created in the **Site Settings > Search schema > Crawled Properties** as per image below:

[image: ows_SupplierName created]

Then, I created a new **Managed Property** called "SupplierName" and mapped the crawled property ows_SupplierName.

[image: Managed Property]

I've reindexed my site after it and then tried to use the POST method in Graph API asking for the field "suppliername", however, the field is not returned.

[image: POST Request https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query]

[image: Response]

Any reason of why it does not return it?